# Unable to run python

Tags: macos, python-2.7

```
Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
```

Unable to run python while running service in Intellij.

Running python should work on my mac.

Comment: python2 is obsolete and should be avoided unless you are actively porting code 2 to 3 ... just use python3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **On local mac python2 is no longer available from macOS Monterey by default.**
- **In order to explicitly install python2 please follow the below steps:**

```
brew install pyenv
pyenv install 2.7.18
echo 'export PATH="$(pyenv root)/versions/2.7.18/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
```